# how to use co with a named function?

Tags: javascript, yield, co

So I am trying to use `co` to wrap around MongoDB methods that return promises
eg
http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/reference/ecmascript6/crud/

I see `co` being used like:

```
co(function*() {
```

which seems like an anonymous function. Fine in the main body of your code, but is there a way to get at the values yielded inside?
eg to basically get at the results of the `co` routine:

If I could do:

```
let wrap = co(function* (collName) {
  let res = yield collection.findOne({});
  yield res;
});
```

and then elsewhere

```
let res = wrap("Topics");
```

but I get

```
TypeError: wrap is not a function
```

Tried also:

```
co(function* wrap(collName) {
```

...

```
co.call(this, wrap("Topics"));
let wrap = co.wrap(function* (collName) { ...
```

but still no luck.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*a way to get at the values yielded inside*"? No, the values inside the generator are asynchronously produced, you cannot access them from the outside synchronously. The result is always a promise.

Comment: does typescript async / await enable this then?

Comment: No, there is absolutely no way to make asynchronous things synchronous. Even ES8 `async` functions will only return promises, and the plain `await`ed values are only available on the inside.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the `co.wrap` function.

```
let wrap = co.wrap(function* (collName) {
  let res = yield collection.findOne({});
  yield res;
});
```

Then you can use it in the way you want

```
let res = wrap("Topics");
```

Comment: that returns a promise, when i'm actually looking for the result of the `findOne` ...

Comment: As other people have said, you cannot do that. When the promise-returning function returns, the value inside the promise won't even be there yet.